# Does involuntary writing divorce 3 times on a paper count?

Tags: sharia, talaq

My husband's family forced my husband write divorce 3 times on a paper even though he didn't want to do it. He did not give me that paper, I was upstairs at that time.

Does that count as a divorce?

Comment: Involuntary acts are invalid

Answer (score 1):

There are some items as the conditions of divorce (Talaq) which ought to be observed. One of the mentioned items is that the man should do it optionally (not by force…). Actually according to the issue above, **it won’t be a correct divorce, because some people forced him to divorce. **

For instance, we can see the opinion of Grand Ayatollah Sistani (as a Shia Marja’ al-Taqlid) that mentioned the issue above that

> The man should divorce optionally (as an optional choice), otherwise
> it is not a valid divorce. (Question 2516 of Ayatollah Sistani …)

Hence I assume that you'd better "don't worry", so it isn't any matter even he has written it three times on the paper, Since he has not done this act optionally, so it won't be an actual divorce. (Thanks God)

**Source:**

http://www.sistani.org/persian/book/50/118/